# Routine call in other namespace

Tags: c#

I wanted to use a DLL library code and link / reference it with my c# code. The reference seems to be working, when defining var instance = new ProjectM1() without any problems.
But in the following line appears an error that ProjectM1 does not contain a definition for ProjectM1 and it couldn't find a extension method (Maybe a using directive or assembly reference is missing)

```
namespace GanttC
{
    public class ProjectM1 : ProjectM1<Task, object>
    {
    }

    public class ProjectM1<T, R> : IProjectM1<T, R>
        where T : Task
        where R : class
    {
        public ProjectM1()             (routine to call !)
        {
            Now = 0;
            Start = DateTime.Now;
            TimeScale = GanttC.TimeScale.Day;
        }
    }
}
```

Here now the main code to call routine ProjectM1 in public class ProjectM1:

```
using GanttC
namespace WindowsApp2
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        Form2 fh;
        public Form4(Form2 caller)
        {
           fh = caller;
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var instance = new ProjectM1();
           instance.ProjectM1();               (error !!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public ProjectM1()` in its current form is a constructor, you can't call it like you're doing

Comment: Philippe, Thanks I got it.